# Django modelchoicefield submit

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, html-select

I have a form that is shown as a dropdown list at the template. When the user selects one option, a javascript function is called and the page reloaded. 
I want to capture the value of the selected option using request.POST.get(...), but I can't manage to set the submission as POST. I have found some approaches using ajax, but I am not familiar with it. Is there any easier way to do it?

home.html:

```
<script>
    function refresh(){
        window.location.href = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/home';
    }
</script>

<form>
    {{ days }}
</form>
```

models.py:

```
class Date(models.Model):
    day = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    month = models.CharField(max_lenght=200, default='')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.day

class CronForm(forms.Form):
    days = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Date.objects.all().order_by('alias'), widget=forms.Select(attrs={"onChange":'refresh()'}))
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes, seems like a perfectly good question to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Submit the form on change

```
class CronForm(forms.Form):
    days = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Date.objects.all().order_by('alias'), 
           widget=forms.Select(attrs={"onChange":'submit()'}))
```

And edit your template to

```
<form method=post>
```

Comment: that's what I do, and it works. the problem is that it is a GET submission, and not a POST one

Comment: oops...use `<form method=post>` in your template.. :)

Comment: just another question @Rajeev. what I get is the position (index) of the selected element from the list. Do you know how can I get the object at that position? thanks!

Comment: Try using the `values_list` to list the required field.

Answer (score 2):

Find the `id` of the dropdown using [firebug](http://getfirebug.com). It should be `id_days` as you are using the name `days`. Then bind jQuery `change` event to it.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(function(){
        $('#id_days').change(function(){
            $('#id_of_form').submit();
        });
    });
</script>

<form id="id_form" method="post" action="." name="form_name" >
    {{ days }}
</form>
```